# Proof of Riemann's Second Bilinear Relation

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $\eta$ be a meromorphic differential and let $\omega$ be a differential with no residue on a Riemann surface $\Sigma$. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the simply connected domain obtained by cutting $\Sigma$ along a canonical basis $\{a_i, b_i \}$ for its homology and consider the map $\mathfrak{u} : \mathcal{L} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $\mathfrak{u}(P) = \int_{P_0}^P \omega$. Here, $P_0 \in \mathcal{L}$ is fixed. In "Riemann Surfaces and Theta Functions" (page 33), Bertola gives the second Riemann bilinear relation as
$$\sum_{Q = \text{pole of } \eta, \omega} \underset{Q}{Res}\ \mathfrak{u} \eta = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{i=1}^g \oint_{b_i} \omega \oint_{a_i} \eta - \oint_{b_i} \eta \oint_{a_i} \omega$$
Bertola then claims that this can be proven using the residue theorem. However, I don't see how the residue theorem can be applied and I'm not sure how to approach this proof. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to approach this proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The boundary of the polygon is segments like $a_ib_ia_i^{-1}b_i^{-1}$
Let $z$ and $z^{\prime}$ be two corresponding points on $a_i$ and $a_i^{-1}$
Let $f=\int \omega$ (its easier to type). 
Now 
$$f(z^{\prime})-f(z)=\int_{z}^{z^{\prime}} \omega=\int_{b_i} \omega$$
where the second equality holds since $b_i$ is between $a_i$ and $a_i^{-1}$, and the portions of $a_i$ and $a_i^{-1}$ integrated over cancel each other out.
Similarly if $z$ and $z^{\prime}$ are two corresponding points on $b_i$ and $b_i^{-1}$
Then 
$$f(z^{\prime})-f(z)=\int_{z}^{z^{\prime}} \omega=\int_{a_i^{-1}} \omega=-\int_{a_i} \omega$$

Now $$\int_{a_i} f\eta +\int_{a_i^{-1}} f\eta=\int_{a_i} (f(z)- f(z^{\prime}))\eta =-\int_{b_i}\omega\int_{a_i}\eta$$

$$\int_{b_i} f\eta +\int_{b_i^{-1}} f\eta=\int_{a_i} (f(z)- f(z^{\prime}))\eta =\int_{a_i}\omega\int_{b_i}\eta$$

The result is

$$\int_C f\omega=\sum\limits_{i=1}^g\int_{a_i}\omega\int_{b_i}\eta-\int_{b_i}\omega\int_{a_i}\eta$$
Where $C$ is the entire boundary.
Now apply the residue theorem to the left hand side.

(there may be some sign difference in my answer and the question, its a question of orientations, conventions, and the highly likely case that I made some sign error.)